# css file in rte_ckeditor in TYPO3 8.7.1 is not reloaded after modification

Tags: typo3

i try to implement own css styles in an individual style sheet file in rte_ckeditor in TYPO3 8.7.1. I run in the problem, that modifications in the style sheet are not recognized until i rename the style sheet.

Deleting the cache dont have any effect. I presume that the browser simply does not reload the style sheet.

Any ideas? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Version 8.7.9 and the issue still seems to exist.

What I do as a workaround is to open the ckeditor configuration (yaml) file as well and add "?v=1" to the defined filename, e.g.:

```
editor:
  config:
    contentsCss: "EXT:tx_yourext/Resources/Public/Css/editor.css?v=1"
```

The yaml file does not get cached, so whenever I do changes in the CSS file, I also change the parameter inside the yaml file.

Answer (score 3):

I found a workaround: Open the linked style sheet in an other browser window and manually reloading (forced reload) the content of this window after every modification. Not really nice - it interrupts the workflow a bit - but it works. After reloading the css the rte shows the new styles.

Comment: This is still a thing in 8.7.8 and you just saved me another hour or more of googling around. Thanks.